# Do our brains have difficulties detecting no?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, neuroscience

In most business seminars, or in movie the secret, for example, it is said that if we want to be rich we need to believe we want to be rich.

We got to want peace, not anti war.
We got to be pro wealth, not anti poverty.

It is said that our subconscious mind can't process not.

So, anti war means want war. Anti poverty means pro poverty.

Is this true?

Which part of our brain subconciously guide us to the outcome we imagine? Is there such thing? Is it true that it cannot process no?

Comment: Regarding, "Which part of our brain subconciously guide us to the outcome we imagine? Is there such thing?" you already have [a question that could use some clarification](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/5455/4086) (i.e., please [edit it](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/posts/5455/edit)), and some good answers (if I may say so myself). You may want to focus this question on the proposed inability to "process no"...and clarify that as well, because you've processed it in writing this question! Whether this is difficult in general is an interesting question though; negative may be unintuitive.

Comment: It's recurring pattern in most biz seminars.